# How to remove all dictionaries from NSMutableArray based on the value in the dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing one iPad application.I have one `NSMutableArray` and `NSMutableDictionary` .These both are changeable based on the data from the web service.I need to remove some dictionary from my `NSMutableArray` based on the `NSMutableDictionary` values. Here I explain the situation through one example:

```
testArray =[{ language :"ESP"},{language :"ENG"},{language :"ENG"},{language :"FRH"}];
```

From the test array i need to remove the all Dictionaries which have key value  language :"ENG".

I've written code like this:

```
 for(int i =0;i<testArray.count;i++){
    NSString *lang  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [testArray[i] objectForKey:@"language"]];
    if([lang isEqualToString:@"ENG"]){
       [testArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
       }
 }
```

But it is not working. I think the problem is when I remove the dictionary from at index the array count is also reducing so the loop is executing based on new array count. Some help me to rewrite the code for get exact answer?

Comment: What specifically is not working about it? Are you getting an exception or is it just that you're not iterating over all of the values?

Comment: What output you get in NSLog which is not expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my favorite way,  it's fast, clear and correct.

```
NSMutableArray *itemsToRemove = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id item in theArray) {
    if ([item shouldBeRemoved])// Condition to check the key pair Value
        [itemsToRemove addObject:item];
}
[theArray removeObjectsInArray:itemsToRemove];
```

Comment: Honestly your approach is really **slow**. You are doing linear search 2 times. The first time you are extracting the items to remove and then you are iterating the second time to actually delete  found elements. I have just compared the performance: 6.03 sec vs. 0.13 sec (using `NSPredicate`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
NSMutableArray *arrTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initwithArray:testArray];
for(int i =0;i<testArray.count;i++){
    NSString *lang  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [testArray[i] objectForKey:@"language"]];
    if([lang isEqualToString:@"ENG"]){
       [arrTemp removeObjectAtIndex:i];
   }
 }
[testArray removeAllObjects];
testArray = arrTemp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i =0;i<testArray.count;i++){
     NSString *lang  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [testArray[i] objectForKey:@"language"]];
    if([lang isEqualToString:@"ENG"]){
       [testArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
       i--;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with below code.

```
NSMutableArray *arrTemp = [NSMutableArray new];
for(int i =0;i<testArray.count;i++){
    NSString *lang  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [testArray[i] objectForKey:@"language"]];
    if([lang isEqualToString:@"ENG"]){

        [arrTemp addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }
}

for(int k=0;k<[arrTemp count];k++)
{
    int ii = [[arrTemp objectAtIndex:k]intValue];
    [testArray removeObjectAtIndex:ii];
}
```

let me know it is working or not!!!

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would implement that using `NSPredicate`:

```
NSMutableArray *testArray = [@[@{ @"language" :@"ESP"}, @{@"language" :@"ENG"},
@{@"language" :@"ENG"}, @{@"language" :@"FRH"}] mutableCopy];
NSPredicate *predicate = 
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"language != %@", @"ENG" ];
testArray = [[testArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
```

I have just tested it, it works (it is short and nice to read, but `NSPredicate` can be really slow).

Another way to do it is using `enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock`:

```
[testArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(NSDictionary *dict, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([dict[@"language"] isEqualToString:@"ENG"]) {
        [testArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
}];
```

Pleace notice that i use `NSEnumerationReverse` as `NSEnumerationOptions` because according to [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObjectAtIndex%3a) of `removeObjectAtIndex:`- Method :

> To fill the gap, all elements beyond index are moved by subtracting 1
>   from their index.